# How do I convert 2D text into a mesh when alt c doesn't work in 2.8

Tags: mesh, text-object

How do I convert 2D text into a mesh when alt c doesn't work in 2.8
I don't understand why this happens maybe they moved the feature elsewhere because in 2.79 in worked fine for me...

Comment: Should still show as available operator in search 'Convert to' appears the hot-key is not set.

Comment: than you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either right click on the text object, and select *Convert to Mesh* or from the *Object* menu select *Convert to* followed by *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*. If you've set selection to right click in preferences, the context menu obviously will not show up when you right click, and in that case you'll be limited to using the *Object* menu, or, as suggested in a comment, searching for it. After clicking your way through the steps, a window that lets you tweak the conversion will appear in the lower left (if it's closed, click the arrow to open it).

[image]

If you right click instead of left click on the menu item, a submenu will appear. From there you can click *Assign Shortcut* to set your own keyboard or mouse shortcut to call this.

[image]

In the same submenu, there's also *Add to Quick Favorites*. The *Quick Favorites* is a user defined menu, that can be called with <kbd>Q</kbd>. [Blender 2.8 Quick Favorites -- A Feature Everyone Will Love?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro_k0STZXoo) has a good description of how this feature works. This video is about six months old, and the UI still looks more like 2.79 than it does in newer builds, but this feature still works the same as in the video.