# After importing a .fbx model in blender it's not smooth with visible faces in viewport as well as render

Tags: modeling, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

I have tried smooth shading, subdivision modifier as well as converting the triangles to squares with alt+j but nothing seems to work.
Album has pictures from fusion as well as blender.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/peU4eVkiR8YQ2E4cA

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: There are multiple images and it was not letting me upload more than one that's why I used shared album.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Screenshot-in-Microsoft-Windows

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Fusion, but I know that the models in that software are geometric representations for mathematically-based models of designs to be used in real life. This means the geometry is automatically generated depending on things such as display resolution, zoom on the model, and model complexity among other things.

When you convert it into an FBX model, Fusion has to decide how to compress this mathematically-based model into an actual geometric model. I believe that unless Fusion doesn't have the setting to increase the resolution of exported models (which I doubt), then this issue isn't necessarily a problem for *Blender*.

Nonetheless, if you cannot make model smoother by using the subsurf modifier, make sure the modifier is visible to both the camera and the viewport (the eye and camera symbols in the modifier tab should be selected):

[image: They will be shaded darker if selected.]

Otherwise, I'd suggest this:

1. Make sure the object is actually a mesh and not something else like curves possibly (if not [convert it into one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127376/how-do-i-convert-2d-text-into-a-mesh-when-alt-c-doesnt-work-in-2-8)).
2. (optional, but might make selection easier) Use Alt+J to turn triangle faces into square faces.
3. Select the hard edges of the model and use Shift+E to add creases.
4. Use the Subsurf Modifier or smooth subdivide to smooth the mesh.

Comment: I'll try and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, all i did was export it in stl format and as fusion supports changing mesh resolution. I was able to get a much better mesh.Thank you.